# Find Taylor series and radius of convergence of $\frac{1}{1-z}, z_0 = i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

I cannot find a comparable series. What am I supposed to compare this to?

$$\frac{1}{1-z}, z_0 = i$$

So I guess this is the geometric series but $z_o = i$. So what's the Taylor series then? Is it just:

$$ \frac{1}{1-z} = 1 + x + x^2 ... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$$
z
I think not... but how do I incorporate the $z_0$

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{1}{{1 - z}} = \frac{1}{{1 - i - (z - i)}} = \frac{1}{{1 - i}}\frac{1}{{1 - (z - i)/(1 - i)}}.
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have\begin{align}\frac1{1-z}&=\frac1{1-i-(z-i)}\\&=\frac1{1-i}\frac1{1-\frac{z-i}{1-i}}\\&=\frac1{1-i}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-i)^n}{(1-i)^n}\text{ (if $|z-i|<\sqrt2$)}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(z-i)^n}{(1-i)^{n+1}}.\end{align}

Comment: where did $\sqrt{2}$ come from?

Comment: From$$\left|\frac{z-i}{1-i}\right|<1\iff\frac{|z-i|}{\sqrt2}<1\iff|z-i|<\sqrt2.$$

Comment: So then is the radius of convergence... $\sqrt{2}$? or is it $\sqrt{2} + i$? by adding i to both sides

Comment: The radius of convergence of a power series is **always** a number $R\in[0,\infty)$ or $\infty$. In this case, it is $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{1-z}= \frac{1}{1-i} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{z-i}{1-i}}.$$

Geometric series !